# Installing twisted on python 3.5 and virtualenv using pip

Tags: python, pip, twisted, python-wheel

when i run

```
pip install twisted
```

in the command line in windows, it starts installing packages until the flowing line comes up.

```
failed building wheel for twisted
```

pip then crashed soon after, saying it has failed the installation.

why is this ?

is there a way round it to install twisted?

my wheel version is 0.29, windows 10. twisted installs fine on python 2.7

thanks

Comment: Anaconda often helps with these types of issues on Windows. Has anyone tried that?

Answer (score 6):

I meet similar problem like yours.You can try to install the Twisted whit wheels

but at first,you should install the wheels

```
pip install wheels
```

then,download an appropriate version from this

website:http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

you can get xxxx.whl file

use

`pip install xxxx/xxxxxx.whl`

Finished!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that is not a programming question (I feel it might as well fit well into https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/).

Could you please provide a tad more information?
What OS are you running? What version?

For comparison, I'm running Debian GNU/Linux (testing), and

```
pip3 install twisted
```

performs fine:

```
collecting twisted
  Using cached Twisted-17.1.0.tar.bz2
Collecting zope.interface>=4.0.2 (from twisted)
  Using cached zope.interface-4.3.3.tar.gz
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from twisted)
  Downloading constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from twisted)
  Downloading incremental-16.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from twisted)
  Using cached Automat-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->twisted)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted)
Collecting attrs (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted)
  Using cached attrs-16.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from setuptools->zope.interface>=4.0.2->twisted)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from setuptools->zope.interface>=4.0.2->twisted)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->zope.interface>=4.0.2->twisted)
Building wheels for collected packages: twisted, zope.interface
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for twisted ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/65/e3/44/cd3da92c03926aabc80e658e11d6e64619abce3ef44c1c34df
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zope.interface ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/00/aa/8b/f1d1eb398423e59894b45ee151344e243808156c2d182c9f4e
Successfully built twisted zope.interface
Installing collected packages: zope.interface, constantly, incremental, attrs, Automat, twisted
Successfully installed Automat-0.5.0 attrs-16.3.0 constantly-15.1.0 incremental-16.10.1 twisted-17.1.0 zope.interface-4.3.3
```

I must admit, this install was done outside of virtualenv.
Did you try installing `twisted` outside your virtualenv?

Comment: I've tried installing it outside my virtualenv and still doesn't work

Comment: it also installs fine with python 2.7

Comment: Would you be so kind and attach a log? That might facilitate finding the problem.